# Need jmespath query to output the id attribute of a filter expression

Tags: json, azure, azure-cli, jmespath

Here is my output from azure cli with `-o json` output.

```
[
  {
"cloudName": "AzureCloud",
"id": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
"isDefault": true,
"name": "CSC Number One",
"state": "Enabled",
"tenantId": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
"user": {
  "name": "user1@gmail.com",
  "type": "user"
}
  },
{
"cloudName": "AzureCloud",
"id": "AAAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAA",
"isDefault": false,
"name": "CSC Number two",
"state": "Enabled",
"tenantId": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
"user": {
  "name": "user1@gmail.com",
  "type": "user"
  }
 }
]
```

I need to print the only id so I can run command:

```
az account list --query [].id
```

This will print all the id for me i.e `xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx` and `AAAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAA`.

Now Id like to print the id only where `name = "CSC Number One"`, which means result should be `xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

- Construct Jmespath query to return the `id` attribute of a filter expression
- Filter expression must match a specific name `CSC Number One`

### Solution

```
@|[? @.name == `CSC Number One` ]|[*].id
```